# Java ASM Opcodes: "H_" prefixed mnemonics (e.g. Opcodes.H_GETFIELD vs. Opcodes.GETFIELD)

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm using the ASM Framework for java bytecode manipulations. Some of the opcode-mnemonics existing twice in ASM, they are prefixed with "H_":

```
Opcodes.H_GETFIELD         vs. Opcodes.GETFIELD
Opcodes.H_GETSTATIC        vs. Opcodes.GETSTATIC
Opcodes.H_INVOKEINTERFACE  vs. Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE
Opcodes.H_INVOKESPECIAL    vs. Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL
Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC     vs. Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC
Opcodes.H_NEWINVOKESPECIAL vs. Opcodes.NEWINVOKESPECIAL
Opcodes.H_PUTFIELD         vs. Opcodes.PUTFIELD
Opcodes.H_PUTSTATIC        vs. Opcodes.PUTSTATIC
```

Whats the difference between these two opcodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `H_` constants in the `Opcodes` class are no actual opcodes, they are used for building a [`MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) (using ASMs [`Handle`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Handle.html) class) which can be used in [`InvokeDynamic`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitInvokeDynamicInsn(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.objectweb.asm.Handle,%20java.lang.Object...)) instructions.